# Concatenate numpy array within a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

I am creating inside a for loop in each iteration of it a numpy array of size `20x30x30x3`. I want to concatenate all of those numpy arrays into a bigger one. If the iteration steps are 100 then the numpy array I want should be`2000x30x30x3`. I tried to do with lists:

```
new_one_arr1_list = []
new_one_arr2_list = []
all_arr1 = np.array([])
for item in one_arr1: # 100 iterations
    item = np.reshape(item, (1, 30, 30, 3))
    new_one_arr1 = np.repeat(item, 20, axis=0)

    all_arr1 = np.concatenate(([all_arr1 , new_one_arr1 ]))
    ind = np.random.randint(one_arr2.shape[0], size=(20,))
    new_one_arr2= one_arr1[ind]

    new_one_arr1_list.append(new_one_arr1)
    new_one_arr2_list.append(new_one_arr2)
```

In each iteration step `new_one_arr1` and `new_one_arr2` they have size `20x30x30x3`. In the end when I am converting `new_one_arr1_list` and `new_one_arr2_list` and the size it is `100x20x30x30x3`. How can I have 2000x30x30x3 in the end in a numpy array?

**EDIT:** I tried to use concatenate to add the arrays within a numpy array `all_arr1` using: `all_arr1= np.concatenate(([all_arr1, new_one_arr1]))` however, I received the message:

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Comment: you use `//` for comment instead of `#`. This code can't compile.

Comment: Yes I add this comment just here (as a clarification).

Comment: Appending to a list in a loop is easier, and faster, than repeated concatenate.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create the concatenation and work around the error, I initialized the array with None and tested if it is None in the loop.
Thereby you do not have to worry about not fitting dimensions.
However, i created some arrays for the ones you did only describe and ended up with a final dimesion of `(400, 30, 30, 3)`.
This fits in here, since `20*20 = 400`.
Hope this helps for you solution.

```
new_one_arr1_list = []
new_one_arr2_list = []
one_arr1 = np.ones((20,30,30,3))
one_arr2 = np.ones((20,30,30,3))
all_arr1 = None
count = 0
for item in one_arr1: # 100 iterations
    item = np.reshape(item, (1, 30, 30, 3))
    new_one_arr1 = np.repeat(item, 20, axis=0)

    # print(all_arr1.shape, new_one_arr1.shape)
    if all_arr1 is None:
        all_arr1 = new_one_arr1
    else:
        all_arr1 = np.concatenate(([all_arr1 , new_one_arr1 ]), axis=0)
    ind = np.random.randint(one_arr2.shape[0], size=(20,))
    new_one_arr2= one_arr1[ind]

    new_one_arr1_list.append(new_one_arr1)
    new_one_arr2_list.append(new_one_arr2)
    count += 1
print(count)
all_arr1.shape
```

Comment: I guess so. Depends on your goals mate

Answer (score 2):

Use np.concatenate operation given in the documenation:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

Don't concatenate in the first iteration, it'll raise dimension error, just copy it during the first iter. For the remaining iterations keep concatenating.

```
new_one_arr1_list = []
new_one_arr2_list = []
all_arr1 = np.array([])
firstIteration = True
for item in one_arr1: # 100 iterations


    item = np.reshape(item, (1, 30, 30, 3))
    new_one_arr1 = np.repeat(item, 20, axis=0)

    if firstIteration:
        all_arr1 = new_one_arr1
        firstIteration=False
    else:
        all_arr1 = np.concatenate(([all_arr1 , new_one_arr1 ]))
    ind = np.random.randint(one_arr2.shape[0], size=(20,))
    new_one_arr2= one_arr1[ind]

    new_one_arr1_list.append(new_one_arr1)
    new_one_arr2_list.append(new_one_arr2)
```

Comment: How can I use it inside the for-loop? I need for example to add an empty array in the first loop.

Comment: I tried to do something like all_arr1= np.array([]) before the for loop and then within the for loop all_arr1= np.concatenate(([all_arr1, new_one_arr1])), however, i am getting error all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
.

Comment: initialize all_arr1 before the for loop. I mean run an iteration first separately then iterate for remaining 99.

Comment: Sorry I did not get the point. You mean to concatenate the numpy arrays within the list?

Comment: In the first iteration don't concatenate. Do the below. 
        all_arr1 = new_one_arr1.                                                                              In the remaining iterations keep concatenating.